# Angular 7 - Dynamic Sorting Array

Tags: angular, sorting, dynamic, angular7

I have an `array` of objects with properties like `name`, `lastUpdated`, etc. The objects are listed in a grid that has sorting options for each of these properties. I have an option also to add a new object to the list. What I want to do is to add it ordered on the list following the sorting criteria applied on that moment.

For example if I have this list:

```
aaaa
bbbb
hhhh
```

with a sorting criteria of name ASC and I add a name like `cccc` I want my list like this:

```
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
hhhh
```

And the same with any sorting criteria applied.

When I apply a sorting criteria I save it on my component on a variable:

```
sortingCriteria;
```

Then when I add a new element to the list I do like:

```
this.list.sort((a, b) => a.Name.localeCompare(b.Name));
```

That orders by name but I need to apply that `sortingCriteria` saved before on this sorting method to order the list properly. Is there any way to use it as a property of the list's objects? Or something to do to filter my list with that sortingCriteria saved? I've tried to use my sorting method which is this one:

```
sortGrid(event) {
    this.sortingCriteria = event.field;
    if (this.list&& this.cols && this.list.length > 0 && this.cols.length > 0) {
      const col = this.cols.filter(x  => x.field === event.field)[0];

      if (col) {
        this.colIndexSelected = col.colIndex;
      }
    }
  }
```

But It's not working I don't know why.

Comment: let me check that post

Comment: That uses javascript I've tried that solution but it's not working on this case

Comment: "That uses javascript"... What do you think Angular is written in? :) I assure you, at least one of the answers to that question will work to sort an array of objects based on a property. Adapting the code to your situation might take some thought; you may not be able to just copy and paste the code directly into your method and get a result, but that's part of programming.